# How to get files matching a pattern using perl Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl, download, sftp

This is my first submitted question at all and I hope someone can help me with this. I never used perl before so any other tips are highly appreciated too.

Lets say I have a perl script with NET::FTP that matches a pattern which can be specified while calling the script. For example:

```
perl ftp.pl '*.txt'
```

To keep it absolute simple, here is what i would do with NET::FTP after establishing the connection to the FTP-Server.

```
$Pattern = '*.*';
$ftp->cwd($FolderAtHost);
my @Files = $ftp->ls($Pattern);
foreach my $File (@Files)
{
     ...
}
```

Now I want to make the same thing with NET::SFTP. but the `ls` Method is completely different. It returns a reference to an Array instead of an array, which is not a big deal.
But I don't find a way to check for a specific file-pattern like: ***.***

I know there is a `wanted =>` option in the `ls` method of the sftp package, but it requires RegEx instead of a file-pattern.

```
sftp->setcwd($FolderAtHost)
my @FilesRef = $sftp->ls(names_only => 1, wanted => qr/.../);
foreach my $File (@$FilesRef)
{
    ...
}
```

Do I have to write a File-Pattern to Regex converter first or is there a simpler way to achieve this?
Maybe matching the filename within the `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Text::Glob](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RCLAMP/Text-Glob-0.09/lib/Text/Glob.pm) especially the glob_to_regex function in it

Comment: Thanks, sound nice. i will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

`Net::SFTP::Foreign` provides the [`glob`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#$sftp-%3Eglob($pattern,-%opts)) method just for that:

```
sftp->setcwd($folder_at_host);
my $files = $sftp->glob('*.jpg');
for my $file (@$files) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now. Thanks to JGNI and the Text::Glob module

after using the module:

```
use Text::Glob 'glob_to_regex';
```

we can use a Pattern like in ftp->ls:

```
$Pattern = *.*;
my $FilesRef = $sftp->ls(names_only => 1, wanted => glob_to_regex($Pattern));
```